# Python Using BeautifulSoup4 and urllib2 to make web spider

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

So here is my code so far.

```
import urlparse
import urllib2
c_s_l = ["anchorage", "fairbanks","kenai","juneau"]
#Craigslist state list

#for city in c_s_l:                      #insert from c_s_l into url[] in city
    #print "https://%s.craigslist.org/search/cta?query=sprinter" % city #substitutes city in city list in url
for city in c_s_l:                      #insert from c_s_l into url[] in city
    base = "https://%s.craigslist.org"% city #substitutes city in city list in url
    url = base + "/search/cta?query=sprinter" 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all('a', class_='result-title hdrlnk'):
        print a
```

I eventually would like to scale up to all of craigslist. But right now I'm trying to figure out how to eliminate things I don't want. Ie Things that are Sprinter vans. thanks for advice and help

Comment: Have a look at [`Scrapy`](http://www.scrapy.org/)

Comment: Also have a look at your craigslist terms of use. Scraping craigslist is prohibited. It is right at the top, under "USE".  https://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use.en